# How to find similar data on certain columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get similar data with two Columns(`Item, Customer`), as per below query i am not getting the first value of a duplicate data.

Please help me to get my expected result like below.

**Sample Data**

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| E_ID |   E_Date   |   Item    | Customer |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
|    1 | 10/10/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      |
|    2 | 10/11/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      |
|    3 | 10/12/2017 | IBM       | UNB      |
|    4 | 10/13/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      |
|    5 | 10/14/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      |
|    6 | 10/15/2017 | SAP       | DIB      |
|    7 | 10/15/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

**My Script**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT E_ID, E_Date,Item,Customer,
         Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY  Customer,Item ORDER By E_ID)AS Rank 
         FROM Events        
) AS B WHERE Rank > 1
```

**Expect the result to be**

```
+------+------------+----------+----------+
| E_ID |   E_Date   |   Item   | Customer |
+------+------------+----------+----------+
|    1 | 10/10/2017 | Mirosoft | DIB      |
|    4 | 10/13/2017 | Mirosoft | DIB      |
|    7 | 10/15/2017 | Mirosoft | DIB      |
|    2 | 10/11/2017 | Oracle   | UNB      |
|    5 | 10/14/2017 | Oracle   | UNB      |
+------+------------+----------+----------+
```

**My actual result**

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+------+
| E_ID |   E_Date   |   Item    | Customer | Rank |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+------+
|    4 | 10/13/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      |    2 |
|    7 | 10/15/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      |    3 |
|    5 | 10/14/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      |    2 |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+------+
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read correctly, you should be using `COUNT` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT E_ID, E_Date, Item, Customer,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Item) AS cnt
    FROM Events        
) t
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY Item, Customer;
```

The above query would return records for every customer/item group having more than one record in that group.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, one ways is to go with EXISTS clause like below

```
SELECT 
  E.E_ID, E.E_Date,E.Item,E.Customer
FROM Events E WHERE EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Events E1 
    WHERE 
      E1.E_ID<>E.E_ID 
      AND E.Item=E1.Item 
      AND E.Customer=E1.Customer
)
```

Answer (score 0):

modified you query a little bit

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.e_id,e.item,e.customer FROM
(
    SELECT E_ID, E_Date,Item,Customer,
         Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY  Customer,Item ORDER By E_ID ) AS Rank 
         FROM Events1      
) AS B join events1 AS e ON (b.item =e.item AND b.customer = e.customer and b.Rank > 1 AND b.Rank > 1 )
```